# Yet another Fragment Communication

Tags: android, android-fragments

There are a lot of questions about fragment communication here, but they are normally question about getting data from activity and sending data back to activity, normally starting from fragment.
But I wonder what what is best approach for sending data from activity to fragment, when you cannot do it when creating fragment? For clarification, Lets assume that an app has 2 fragments that **can use** (can not must) some data to improve user experience, but obtaining this data is costly. So obtain this data in activity using a `Loader` or `AsyncTask` in main activity while creating Fragments themselves. Now when data is ready asynchronously in Activity, we need to send this data to Fragments. What is best approach for this? I thought of a way for doing this, and I like to know if there is any problem with this approach.

1-In fragment we use `onAttach` to send fragment to activity and check if any data is already read:

```
@Override
public void onAttach (Activity activity) {
    MyActivity act = (MyActivity)activity;
    act.addFragment(this);
    Data data = act.getData();
    if (data != null) {
        setAdditionData(data)
    }
}
```

2-and in activity store a `WeakReference` to Fragment:

```
private ArrayList<WeakReference<Fragment>> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
...
public void addFragment(Fragment frag) {
    WeakReference<Fragment> f = new WeakReference<Fragment>(frag);
    mFragments.add(f);
}

public Data getData() {
    return mData;
}

public void updateFragmentsData() {
    for (Iterator<WeakReference<Fragment>> iterator = mFragments.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        WeakReference<Fragment> wf = iterator.next();
        Fragment f = wf.get();
        if (f != null) {
            f.setAdditionData(mData);
        } else {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Now when fragments attaches, it adds itself to list of fragments in activity and checks if data is already ready and if ready it will use that data. On the other hand, when data is ready asynchronously in activity, it can call `updateFragmentsData()` to update all fragments data.

I wonder if this approach is correct or it can be incorrect in some situations? Any idea? Is there any better approach for notifying fragments from main activity?

Btw, is it possible to use Handler/Message for communicating between fragments too or not? As another approach?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of three ways.

1. Use a listener. Write an interface in the activity to use it as a listener. The fragment implements the interface and registers and unregister as a listener at appropriate time.(say at onCreateView and onDestroyView).
2. This one is my favorite. I hope DataBinding is gaining popularity and it can be used to solve this. Say you define a particular model for the fragment layout. Now you use [ObservableFields](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#observablefields)  in the model. Pass this model to your databinding variable. Now change this object from either the activity or the fragment itself, changes will be reflected in the view.
3. The newly introduced [ViewModels](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html). I will be using them from my next project.

Comment: Oh, this ViewModels seems really cool. They can handle inter fragment/activity data passing well. :) Thanks a lot.